# Three finger gestures only working in touchscreen

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, gestures

I have just updated to Ubuntu 22 and tried using 3 finger gestures.
Although these work fine when i use the touchscreen, they do not work in the trackpad...
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 22 would mean you are running Ubuntu Core 22 the only version of Ubuntu to use just single digit version number.

Comment: perhaps try https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchegg